# Remove special characters in linux files

Tags: linux, special-characters

I have a lot of files *.java, *.xml. But a guy wrote some comments and Strings with spanish characters. I been searching on the web how to remove them.

I tried `find . -type f -exec sed 's/[áíéóúñ]//g' DefaultAuthoritiesPopulator.java` just as an example, how can i remove these characters from many other files in subfolders?

Comment: I bet some form of iconv will get you going; but I don't know exactly what you need so I'll stick with a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do such a wicked thing???

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you really want, you can use `find`, almost as you are using it.

```
find -type f \( -iname '*.java' -or -iname '*.xml' \) -execdir sed -i 's/[áíéóúñ]//g' '{}' ';'
```

The differences:

- The path `.` is implicit if no path is supplied.
- This command only operates on *.java and *.xml files.
- `execdir` is more secure than `exec` (read the man page).
- `-i` tells `sed` to modify the file argument in place.  Read the man page to see how to use it to make a backup.
- `{}` represents a path argument which `find` will substitute in.
- The `;` is part of the `find` syntax for `exec`/`execdir`.

Answer (score 0):

You're *almost* there :)

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/[áíéóúñ]//g' {} \;
                         ^^                 ^^
```

From `sed(1)`:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
          edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

From `find(1)`:

```
   -exec command ;
          Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All
          following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to
          the command until an argument consisting of `;' is
          encountered.  The string `{}' is replaced by the current
          file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the
          arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it
          is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these
          constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or
          quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See
          the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the -exec
          option.  The specified command is run once for each
          matched file.  The command is executed in the starting
          directory.   There are unavoidable security problems
          surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the
          -execdir option instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is the tool for the job:

```
NAME
       tr - translate or delete characters

SYNOPSIS
       tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

DESCRIPTION
       Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writing to standard out‐
       put.

       -c, -C, --complement
              use the complement of SET1

       -d, --delete
              delete characters in SET1, do not translate

       -s, --squeeze-repeats
              replace each input sequence of a repeated character that is listed in SET1  with  a
              single occurrence of that character
```

piping your input through `tr -d áíéóúñ` will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to remove only characters with diacritic signs? It probably worth removing all characters with codes not in the range `0-127`, so removal regexp will be `s/[\0x80-\0xFF]//g` if you're sure that your files should not contain higher ascii.